# SQL Mail does not work with the 64-bit version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, exec, sqlmail

My requirement is that I want to send email from MS SQL Server whenever table called "CustomerInfo" is updated. But I am getting error "SQL Mail does not work with the 64-bit version of SQL Server" whenever table is updated.

Steps that I followed -

1. Created table and trigger from - http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/creating-email-triggers-in-sql-server-2005
2. Then configured xp_sendmail

   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1';
   reconfigure
   exec sp_configure 'SQL Mail XPs', 1
   reconfigure
3. Then configured the DB mail as given here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29060/SQL-SERVER-2008-Configure-Database-Mail-Send-Email

Now when I update the table I get error -

```
SQL Mail does not work with the 64-bit version of SQL Server
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Mail is deprecated. Use [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Database mail doesn't require a MAPI profile and can send mail over SMTP.